# Проблема с активацией почты

Tags: php

Написал регистрацию и активацию почты пользователей на сайте. На почту приходит письмо с ссылкой, по который нужно перейти, чтобы активировать почту, но при переходе  по ссылке я получаю ошибку

```
Not Found
The requested URL /activation/6efb67bfedc38467d2d10200a98b19e2 was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Вот код файла с активацией:

```
<?php 


//Добавляем файл подключения к БД

require_once("dbconnect.php");


//Проверяем, если существует переменная token в глобальном массиве GET

if(isset($_GET['token']) && !empty($_GET['token'])){

    $token = $_GET['token'];

}else{

    exit("<p><strong>Ошибка!</strong> Отсутствует проверочный код.</p>");

}



//Проверяем, если существует переменная email в глобальном массиве GET

if(isset($_GET['email']) && !empty($_GET['email'])){

    $email = $_GET['email'];

}else{

    exit("<p><strong>Ошибка!</strong> Отсутствует адрес электронной почты.</p>");

}



//Удаляем пользователей с таблицы users, которые не подтвердили свою почту в течении сутки

$query_delete_users = $mysqli->query("DELETE FROM `users` WHERE `email_status` = 0 AND `date_registration` < ( NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY )");

if(!$query_delete_users){

    exit("<p><strong>Ошибка!</strong> Сбой при удалении просроченного аккаунта. Код ошибки: ".$mysqli->errno."</p>");

}


//Удаляем пользователей из таблицы confirm_users, которые не подтвердили свою почту в течении сутки

$query_delete_confirm_users = $mysqli->query("DELETE FROM `confirm_users` WHERE `date_registration` < ( NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)");

if(!$query_delete_confirm_users){

    exit("<p><strong>Ошибка!</strong> Сбой при удалении просроченного аккаунта(confirm). Код ошибки: ".$mysqli->errno."</p>");

}



//Делаем запрос на выборке токена из таблицы confirm_users
$query_select_user = $mysqli->query("SELECT `token` FROM `confirm_users` WHERE `email` = '".$email."'");


//Если ошибок в запросе нет
if(($row = $query_select_user->fetch_assoc()) != false){


    //Если такой пользователь существует
    if($query_select_user->num_rows == 1){

        //Проверяем совпадает ли token
        if($token == $row['token']){

            //Обновляем статус почтового адреса 
            $query_update_user = $mysqli->query("UPDATE `users` SET `email_status` = 1 WHERE `email` = '".$email."'");

            if(!$query_update_user){

                exit("<p><strong>Ошибка!</strong> Сбой при обновлении статуса пользователя. Код ошибки: ".$mysqli->errno."</p>");

            }else{

                //Удаляем данные пользователя из временной таблицы confirm_users
                $query_delete = $mysqli->query("DELETE FROM `confirm_users` WHERE `email` = '".$email."'");

                if(!$query_delete){

                    exit("<p><strong>Ошибка!</strong> Сбой при удалении данных пользователя из временной таблицы. Код ошибки: ".$mysqli->errno."</p>");

                }else{

                    //Подключение шапки
                    require_once("header.php");

                        //Выводим сообщение о том, что почта успешно подтверждена.
                        echo '<h1 class="success_message text_center">Почта успешно подтверждена!</h1>';
                        echo '<p class="text_center">Теперь Вы можете войти в свой аккаунт.</p>';

                    //Подключение подвала
                    require_once("footer.php");
                }

                // Завершение запроса удаления данных из таблицы confirm_users
                $query_delete->close();
            }

            // Завершение запроса обновления статуса почтового адреса
            $query_update_user->close();



        }else{ //if($token == $row['token'])
            exit("<p><strong>Ошибка!</strong> Неправильный проверочный код.</p>");
        }

    }else{ //if($query_select_user->num_rows == 1)
        exit("<p><strong>Ошибка!</strong> Такой пользователь не зарегистрирован </p>");
    }

}else{ //if(($row = $query_select_user->fetch_assoc()) != false)
    //Иначе, если есть ошибки в запросе к БД
    exit("<p><strong>Ошибка!</strong> Сбой при выборе пользователя из БД. </p>");
}


// Завершение запроса выбора пользователя из таблицы users
$query_select_user->close();

//Закрываем подключение к БД
$mysqli->close();

?>
```

Comment: А с чего вы взяли, что вы вообще в свой код попадаете, переходя по ссылке?

Comment: @ArchDemon а как можно проверить?

Comment: Вы уже проверили. Код 404 - страница не найдена.

Comment: @ArchDemon Как можно пофиксить проблему?

Comment: Указать правильную ссылку в письме